# Repeated laptop battery failures -- bad batteries or bad motherboard?

Tags: laptop, battery

I replaced my ASUS laptop battery because the charge light started blinking orange and the battery would only last a couple of minutes before dying. This condition started suddenly, not with the usual slow decay in life. A new battery solved the problem, but after a few weeks the same thing happened again. I've now replaced the battery three times and still have the same problem. Obviously, either the computer charging circuit has a problem or the batteries are failure prone. So far, I have used generic batteries (not from ASUS).

My question is whether it's worth buying an original battery to see if I have better results, or whether this is most likely a motherboard problem. While I realize that 3rd party batteries may not be as good as the brand name ones, it seems a bit unlikely to me that three would fail in the same way, so I'm hesitant to invest in a relatively expensive "original" battery if my computer is just going to destroy it.

Comment: It would be a waste of money to buy brand ones now.  
You can't escape customer service here. (I think.) | But the question is also kinda too specific.

Comment: To be more general, I guess the question would be, "How common is it for generically sold laptop batteries to experience sudden failure?"

Comment: I agree with pnuts, but if that fails send the lot back to Asus if it is expensive laptop and pay for fix (if out of warranty), other wise, consider a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I would dare say this is what you get for buying generic batteries? It's your call, but I would also think you may even have a bad power cable? If its not sending clean power, you're just killing batteries.